# Rename Stored Procedure in Google BigQuery

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

BigQuery does not allow you to rename a table name or a column name. The only option is to take a copy of the table and specify the new table name in BigQuery. This doesn't incur any additional charges other than the additional cost of storage

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MYDATASET.MYTABLE_NEW AS 
SELECT * FROM MYDATASET.MYTABLE;

DROP TABLE MYDATASET.MYTABLE;
```

Can I do something similar for Stored procedures via BigQuery Standard SQL? I didn't find anything in the documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this workaround solution:

**[1]:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mydataset.add(INOUT x INT64, y INT64)
BEGIN  
  SET x = x + y;
END;
```

**[2]:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mydataset.add_new(INOUT x INT64, y INT64)
BEGIN  
  call mydataset.add(x, y);
END;
```

Comment: But I can still access the procedure with old name i.e `add`

Comment: Manual option is; `[1]` Open Google console `[2]` Click on the Stored Procedure Name & Click Edit Stored Procedure `[3]` Rename & Run `[4]` Delete the old Stored Procedure

Comment: @Abhishek; please let me know if it helped. Also consider to accept/vote up the answer if it is useful !